# Can't Stackoverflow allow some other content servers for storing profile pictures?

Tags: feature-request, feedback

I just signed up for Gravatar, chose a username and found that they don't allow people to delete accounts (I know I can hide the account, but that's not enough). While annoyed already, I wanted to submit some feedback to them and they don't have a feedback option either.
Why is StackOverflow associated with only a website like Gravatar?
Couldn't StackOverflow allow profile images to be accessed from Picassa, imagebucket or some other content server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gravatar isn't very user friendly (which is why I still have a generic gravatar).  It'd be nice if we had options.

Comment: "Gravatar isn't very user friendly" - Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

If you have looked in the FAQ (Common Questions in the Help Menu) you would've found the following question:

> OK, but how do I contact support?

With the answer:

> Send an e-mail to support at gravatar dot com

Also, if you would've looked at the privacy policy, you would've found out it is operated by Automattic, which does have a contact page.

Lastly, the reason they aren't able to delete an account, is due to they "global auth", using the same credentials for wordpress.com, askimet API keys, and gravatar. (not that different when compared with stackexchange)

Comment: But... SE accounts _can_ be deleted. All you have to do is ask.

Comment: that's because SE uses a better system *;)*